# celery dont do anything after recived a task from rabbitmq

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

iam running a simpel task to send email to user after ordering somthing in my django app
i am using RabbitMQ as broker and i am running it on docker using :

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:management
```

and running celery with

```
celery -A myshop worker -l info
```

i have this in my celery.py beside my setting.py file in main django app :

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')

app = Celery('myshop')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

and in the **init**.py file of the main django app :

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

and this is the task in one of my django app

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order


@shared_task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task to send an e-mail notification when an order is
    successfully created.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = f'Order nr. {order.id}'
    message = f'Dear {order.first_name},\n\n' \
              f'You have successfully placed an order.' \
              f'Your order ID is {order.id}.'
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          'email@gmail.com',
                          [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

celery getting the order like this :

```
[2024-01-25 16:12:51,674: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.task.order_created[679c4592-e5e2-42f4-9f15-b07f9492fce3] received
[2024-01-25 16:12:53,193: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 15812 calling self.run()
[2024-01-25 16:12:53,194: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 17712 calling self.run()
[2024-01-25 16:12:54,869: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 22180 calling self.run()
```

and doing nothing for a long time and after maybe 30 minute i get this error from celery console :

```
[2024-01-25 16:15:55,025: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: PreconditionFailed(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery 
acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers d
oc guide to learn more', (0, 0), '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 332, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 628, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\loops.py", line 130, in synloop
    connection.drain_events(timeout=2.0)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 341, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 171, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 526, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 532, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 53, in on_frame
    callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 538, in on_inbound_method
    return self.channels[channel_id].dispatch_method(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 156, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "E:\Projects\app\myshop\Lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 293, in _on_close
    raise error_for_code(
amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: (0, 0): (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Time
out value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
```

and this one from rabbitmq console :

```
2024-01-25 14:45:54.969418+00:00 [info] <0.876.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.876.0> (172.17.0.1:51326 -> 172.17.0.2:5672)
2024-01-25 14:45:54.976004+00:00 [info] <0.876.0> connection <0.876.0> (172.17.0.1:51326 -> 172.17.0.2:5672): user 'guest' au
thenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2024-01-25 15:15:55.020490+00:00 [warning] <0.828.0> Consumer 2 on channel 1 has timed out waiting for delivery acknowledgeme
nt. Timeout used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
2024-01-25 15:15:55.020948+00:00 [error] <0.828.0> Channel error on connection <0.810.0> (172.17.0.1:51538 -> 172.17.0.2:5672
, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
2024-01-25 15:15:55.020948+00:00 [error] <0.828.0> operation none caused a channel exception precondition_failed: delivery ac
knowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc
 guide to learn more
```

i even try to install flower and see the console of the celery there but i get nothing from that